# State changed from starting to crashed на heroku

Tags: java, maven, jar, heroku

Пытаюсь заставить работать Discord бота, написанного на Java с использованием maven, на Heroku, но уже который раз сталкиваюсь с ошибкой, которая возникает через где-то полторы минуты после его работы:

```
2020-05-14T10:33:49.399007+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-14T10:33:49.402895+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2020-05-14T10:33:49.647167+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-05-14T10:33:49.647175+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2020-05-14T10:33:49.647257+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-05-14T10:33:50.958273+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
2020-05-14T10:33:50.958447+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
2020-05-14T10:33:50.958596+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
2020-05-14T10:33:51.094243+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO JDA - Login Successful!
2020-05-14T10:33:51.480321+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
2020-05-14T10:33:51.777596+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
2020-05-14T10:35:17.031713+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-14T10:35:17.100783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-14T10:35:21.767199+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-14T10:35:21.770362+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2020-05-14T10:35:21.923628+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-05-14T10:35:21.923658+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2020-05-14T10:35:21.923697+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-05-14T10:35:22.937892+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
2020-05-14T10:35:22.937954+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
2020-05-14T10:35:22.938031+00:00 app[web.1]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
2020-05-14T10:35:23.156852+00:00 app[web.1]: [main] INFO JDA - Login Successful!
2020-05-14T10:35:23.494047+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
2020-05-14T10:35:23.765339+00:00 app[web.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
2020-05-14T10:36:50.388988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Через какое-то, всегда произвольное, время процесс снова начинается заново уже на самом сервере, снова живет полторы минуты и заканчивается той же ошибкой.

Вычитал много информации по поводу таких случаев, в том числе здесь, перепробовал фокусы с Procfile, которые приводили к другой ошибке (изначально Procfile отсутствовал в корне проекта, при деплое на хероку через консоль он создавался его сам):

Код Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Ошибка в логах на хероку:

```
2020-05-14T10:19:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-14T10:19:24.074846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-14T10:19:23.994498+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-14T10:19:23.995816+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
```

Убираю из корня Procfile, все становится как в первом блоке.

Сейчас файл pom.xml выглядит следующим образом:

```
<groupId>org.morobot</groupId>
<artifactId>MoroBot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>morobot.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1_150</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> </project>
```

Локально все работает прекрасно. В чем может быть причина крашей?